# SQL left join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table1

```
Id           value
1               1
1               4
```

Table2

```
id      Detailid          value
 1       1                 1
 1       2                 2
 1       3                 3
 1       4                 4
 1       5                 5
 1       6                 6
```

I want results

```
Id      Detaild      value
1        1           1
1        2          null
1        3          null 
1        4          4
1        5          null
1        6          null
```

My query below gives me 2 extra rows with null

```
select distinct t1.id,t2.detailid  
 ,case when t1.value IN(t2.Value) then t1.value else null end as value  
from table1 t1  
left outer join table2 t2  
on t1.id= t2.id
```

I am getting

```
Id       Detaild    value  
1        1          null ----dont need  
1        1          1  
1        2          null  
1        3          null   
1        4          null ---dont need  
1        4          4  
1        5          null  
1        6          null
```

Comment: Let's see the select statement you have.

Comment: Also, you have 2 rows in Table1, and 6 rows in Table2. In your "I want results", you state that you want DetailId's 1, 2, 3, 4; where values 2 and 3 don't exist in EITHER table. Your query will never work.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? because your required results is not applicable

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to get a RANGE for ID 1 between its DetailIds?

Comment: That is correct I am trying to get a range for Id 1 but if id 1 exists in table one then I want that value from table 1 but if does not then I want null as value

Comment: ahmed-alaa-el-din: I have updated the Results, Sorry for the cnfusion

Comment: I edited my answer based on your last modifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking in to it. I looked at my real data situation and I think I needed to update the table 1 and table 2 columns.I am extremely sorry for re updating the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have given as data, this query will do the trick :

```
SELECT isnull(t1.Id,1), t2.Detailid, t1.value 
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.Detailid = t2.Detailid AND t1.ID = 1
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c808/8/0

EDIT :

So take a look at the following query, based on you last edit :

```
SELECT t2.Id, t2.Detailid, t1.value 
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.value = t2.value
WHERE t2.Id = 1
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94f21a/5/0

RE-EDIT :

```
SELECT t2.Id, t2.Detailid, t1.value 
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.value = t2.value
WHERE t2.id IN (SELECT Id FROM Table1)
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beede/7/0

If `(SELECT Id FROM Table1)` returns too many rows, try something like this instead :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t2.Id, t2.Detailid, t1.value 
 FROM Table2 AS t2
 INNER JOIN Table1 AS t ON t.Id = t2.Id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.value = t2.value
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beede/9/0

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I looked at my real data situation and I think I needed to update the table 1 and table 2 columns.I am extremely sorry for re updating the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works perfect as per the data that I gave. Just need one more clarification if there are multiple IDs in the table then where clause cannot be specific is their a workaround for where clause

Comment: If it's what you are looking for : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee0ad/1/0 just remove the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I have added more data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beede/1/0  Added ID 3 in table 2 but it is not in table 1. I do not want ID 3 in results

Comment: Sorry for going back and forth too many times. Tis is my first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't have a row in Table1 with a foreign key to DetailId 2 and 3, so how else can it return those in the join?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.Id, t2.DetailId, t1.value 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2. ON t1.DetailId = t2.detailId 
WHERE t2.DetailId NOT IN (5,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.DetailId, t1.value 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2. ON t1.Detaild = t2.detailid;
```

Use the above query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.[Id],t2.Detailid,t1.value
from Table2 t2
left join Table1 t1
on t2.value = t1.value;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d70dd/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works perfect as per the data that I gave. Just need one more clarification if there are multiple IDs in the table then where clause cannot be specific is their a workaround for where clause

Comment: sorry. I didn't get you. Can you give me some sample data and expected output. Please edit the question to reflect the same.